# Deleting PDF file while it is open in a PDF reader

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I have checked Adobe, Foxit, and Nitro reader. None of them let you delete the pdf file while the PDF is open. Chrome web browser lets you delete pdf files while they are open.
Even I couldn't find a way to delete files from the PDF readers by themselves.
(In order to reduce the time to review a large number of PDFs, I would like to delete some of them while they are open.)

Comment: So why not just continue to use Chrome? It seems to fit your requirement...

Comment: @spikey_richie, For commenting and some other tools. And I don't want Chrome to be my default pdf viewer.